# Hide cursor when idle

Tags: wpf, timer, mouse

In my WPF app, I want to hide the cursor when it hasn't moved for a number of seconds.
If it is moved, I want to show it again.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `MouseMove` event like this :

**Tested code:**

```
myTimer = new Timer(3000);
myTimer.AutoReset = false;
myTimer.Elapsed += delegate { MouseExt.SafeOverrideCursor(Cursors.None); }; //Hide cursor

private void MyView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     myTimer.Stop();
     Mouse.OverrideCursor = null; //Show cursor
     myTimer.Start();
}
```

This is a helper for dispatching properly the call to override the Cursor:

```
public static class MouseExt
{
    public static void SafeOverrideCursor(Cursor cursor)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = cursor;
        }));
    }
}
```

When the timer elapses the cursor is hidden. When its moved it reappears and timer is reset.

Comment: Doesn't work. Nothing is happening. As I read the code, this will hide the mouse for 3 seconds, then show it again.

Comment: @Annish, Told you it was untested... I forgot to Start the timer :D also i was not handling properly the OverrideCursor. It works now.

Comment: I dont think OverrideCursor  is well for when I active the software by other that it will never show the cursor.